# How import a helper file that isn't a controller helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Suppose I have a random file in a rails app: `myapp/app/random_folder/random_helper.rb`.

How can I load / require this file in the rails console?

#### Example

I have the file `myapp/spec/spec_helper.rb` and I want to require/load those helpers in the rails console.

#### What I've tried

I tried

```rb
require 'spec_helper'
require_relative 'spec/spec_helper.rb'
require_relative 'spec/spec_helper'
require_relative 'spec_helper'
```

but none of these approaches work.

Answer (score 0):

It was a bug between the keyboard and chair. This does work:

```rb
require_relative 'path/to/some_helper'
```

Read the error message carefully because after loading the helper, an error may be produced, which is very different to a failure to load the helper file at all.

In my case, I saw `NoMethodError: undefined method 'configure' for RSpec:Module` and mistook it for an inability to load the helper file, but it was in fact loading the helper file but an error resulted from something in the helper file.

I will not accept this answer because it may not be the best way to load a random helper file, but hopefully it may be useful to someone else.